# Chrome Devtools shows outdated js source for frame after reload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

have script in a frame:

[image]

now I move "debugger" from line 2207 to 2209, save and reload the frame.

[image]

Chrome debugger stopped on 2209, but shown source code is outdated.

'**Disable cache**' on DevTools is **checked**. 
Helps only reloading whole page.

How do I get chrome Dev tools to show the js source correctly??

Answer (score 0):

On top right of DevTools, click the "3 dots" menu and select "Settings". There you may wanna check "Disable cache(while DevTools is open)".

Also, on MacOS you can use at any moment (even with DevTools closed)the shortcut "Command + Shift + R" to force a full refresh of the page.

Comment: That option is checked. Reloading hole page works, but it's not what I want. It is terribly uncomfortable.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The "debugger" just makes it a "Break Point" right? If yes, have you tried to remove this debuggers and double click above 2207 and 2209. It will put a blue marker on each line number telling you it is a break point.

Comment: it's just sample to show the problem. no matter where 'debugger' is.
I need fresh source code while debugging after reload frame. Because code could be totally different, and when i debug line by line i can't see what I really debuggin